# How to make a script run like a daemon waiting for changes in 2 files?

Tags: bash, scripting, daemon, inotify

I am new to scripting, I made a script that reads 2 files and execute commands and as output a log file.

I want this script to run like a daemon and wait for changes in these 2 files to execute these commands again on theses files.

I am aware of using some inotify, but I don't know exactly how to use it and where to place the loop so the script will work as I want it too, that is:

1. user executes the script for the first time
2. this script reads these files and make the output log
3. the script "sleeps" (daemonized) until these 2 log files change (some lines added to them)
4. execute the same script again on these files
5. sleep again and wait for changes in these 2 files

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062806/inotify-how-to-use-it-linux

Comment: @GAD3R yea i noticed that so i edited my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this might help you out so I'll post it as an "answer" (if I could just comment I would do that).

http://www.nongnu.org/fileschanged/

Example 4 might be in the area of what you're trying to do. I've used it in the distant past with good results.

```
./fileschanged -r dir | while read file ; do
  if [ "${file}" == "x" ] ; then
    handle_file_x_script "${file}"
  else if [ "${file}" == "y" ] ; then
    handle_file_y_script "${file}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/172939)

Comment: yeah, if i could COMMENT on the post i would have just posted it as a comment.  but i can't, so rather than not help the OP i put it here anyway.  I'm not saying that's an answer.

Comment: You could simply copy/paste and edit sample line, that would be a answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had to monitor an old software, which does not have enough logging options.
It is not exactly what you want, but might help you.

- compares 2 files (`ref.cfg` and `cur.cfg`) every second
- logs to file `cfg.log` if a diff is detected
- makes a diff to a file if a change is detected
- makes a backup of the file with date suffix

`watch_cfg.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cfg_reference="/tmp/ref.cfg"
cfg_current="/tmp/cur.cfg"

while true; 
do 
  cfg1=$(cat $cfg_reference)
  cfg2=$(cat $cfg_current)
  date_current="$(date +"%F_%T")"
  diff_detected=false
  test "$cfg1" = "$cfg2" || diff_detected=true
  if [ "$diff_detected" = true ]; then
    printf "$date_current [cfg] diff detected\n" >> cfg.log
    diff $cfg_reference $ecfg_current > "./cfg_diff/cur.cfg_${date_current}"
    cp -a "$cfg_reference" "./cfg_old/cur.cfg_before_${date_current}"
    cp -a "$cfg_current" "$cfg_reference"
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Run those commands:

```
chmod +x watch_cfg.sh
nohup ./watch_cfg.sh  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This detaches the process from the current session and sends it to the background.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/) to listen to inotify events. Packages are availables in debian-like (ubuntu,…) distribution and probably in others as well